# How to append a div thats created on a click function to another div before being deleted? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a `<div>` thats created upon a click function and it animates into to the other side of the screen. Afterwards, on `"animationend"`, it  is being deleted. However, I want to append the created element either on `"animationend"` or `"animationstart"` onto my div/class of `recentTaps`.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway"
        rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Tap Music</title>
    </head>
  <div class="recent">
    <h2>Recent Taps</h2>
    <hr />
    <span id="recentTaps" class="recentTaps">stuf</span>
  </div>
  <div class="visual"></div>
  <div class="pads">
    <div class="pad1">
      <audio src="./assets/sounds/bubbles.mp3" class="sound"></audio>
    </div>
    <div class="pad2">
      <audio class="sound">
        <source src="./assets/sounds/ufo.mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="pad3">
      <audio class="sound">
        <source src="./assets/sounds/clay.mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="pad4">
      <audio class="sound">
        <source src="./assets/sounds/confetti.mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="pad5">
      <audio class="sound">
        <source src="./assets/sounds/glimmer.mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="pad6">
      <audio class="sound">
        <source src="./assets/sounds/moon.mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
</section>
```

Above, you can see my HTML code.
Below is my Javascript:

```
   window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound");
    const pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div");
    const visual = document.querySelector(".visual");
    //const recent = document.getElementById("recentTaps");

    const colors = [
        "#60d394",
        "#d36060",
        "#c060d3",
        "#d3d160",
        "#6860d3",
        "#60b2d3"
    ];

    //lets get going with the sound here
    pads.forEach((pad, index) => {
        pad.addEventListener("click", function() {
        sounds[index].currentTime = 0;
        sounds[index].play();
        createBubbles(index);
        });
    });

    //Create a function that makes bubbles
    const createBubbles = index => {
        const bubble = document.createElement("div");
        visual.appendChild(bubble);
        bubble.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
        bubble.style.animation = "jump 3s ease";
        bubble.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
        visual.removeChild(bubble);
        });
    };
    });
```

CSS is below:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }

    hr {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 75%;
    }

    .recent {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .recent span {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    }

    .app {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }

    header h1 {
    margin: 50px 0px 30px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    }

    header p {
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .pads {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    }

    .pads > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    flex: 1;
    }

    .pad1 {
    background: #60d394;
    }

    .pad2 {
    background: #d36060;
    }

    .pad3 {
    background: #c060d3;
    }

    .pad4 {
    background: #d3d160;
    }

    .pad5 {
    background: #6860d3;
    }

    .pad6 {
    background: #60b2d3;
    }

    .visual > div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: -1;
    }

    @keyframes jump {
    0% {
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 20%;
    }
    33% {
        bottom: 60%;
        left: 20%;
    }
    66% {
        bottom: 60%;
        left: 80%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 80%;
    }
    }
```

I've tried `appendChild()` on `"animationend"` and vice-versa. The console gives me an error. I've also tried, `append()`. I'm going for an append on my other div before it's deleted and while still deleting the element that created on the original div.

Comment: `a.removeChild(b)` returns `b`, so you can do `newParent.appendChild(currentParent.remove(child))`

Comment: Thanks, after I added that comment and it added it to my other div. I was able to put some css on it using `::before`.